# I'm not sure how to pass a soap header value using Zeep in python

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I have an API token that needs to be passed as a SOAP header value using zeep but I'm not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated. Heres what I've got so far. Thanks :)

```
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)


client = Client('URL', settings=settings)
client.service.GetDeparture(X,X)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass them in the session.

```
from requests import Session

s = Session()
s.headers['Accept-Encoding'] = "gzip,deflate"
s.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"

settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client('URL', settings=settings, transport=Transport(session=s))
client.service.GetDeparture(X,X)
```